# How to create multiple instances of a Native Module?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a Native Module that is launching a request and retrieving data to pass back it to JavaScript. (context: DFP Custom Rendering [Android Doc](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native) - [iOS Doc](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/native))

I have trouble understanding why I can only create one instance of the Native Module. Having only one instance is not working for me because if the module is used simultaneously by multiple JS components, so that each component can get its own data from Native Module, they will override the Native Module properties and the callbacks from native code will be fired for all the JS components that use the Native Module.

That's how I call the native module from JavaScript:

`const RNDFPNativeAds = NativeModules.RNDFPNativeAds;`

Therefore every time I import this variable into a component, it's the same instance of the native module which is called.

It would have been great to be able to do something like this to solve my issue:

`const RNDFPNativeAd_Number1 = new NativeModules.RNDFPNativeAds();
const RNDFPNativeAd_Number2 = new NativeModules.RNDFPNativeAds();`

To have more context on my issue, here is a gist of the native code used for iOS: [iOS Native code](https://gist.github.com/ou2s/b4c3928e541c2f4b01c04bf34e8d225f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't with React Native at the moment (version 0.50). We ended up doing a single instance that handles all the requests. You can maybe bypass the single instance limitation by using a native component which won't render any view, but we were not comfortable with this approach because native components are used to display.

Comment: why are native modules used to display? I mean he wants to do non-visual stuff, so this is just like a native worker thread.

Comment: We don't use Native modules to display. I did not understand your comment sorry, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, i was reading the `but we were not comfortable with this approach because native components are used to display` sentence and thought you wanted to state that react native modules are used only for rendering. But you can use them for all purposes. My reading fault.

Comment: @MartinMlostek No problem :) I think it's because of the confusion between native module and native component. By the way, what did you mean by `like a native worker thread` ?

Comment: @ou2s When I use this NativeModules.SomeNativeClass to call a method in SomeNativeClass, it is always a new instance. Because of this I am not a able to dismiss a view controller. Do you have any idea on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620105/dismiss-a-view-controller-from-react-native